# PHP Mess detector - Cannot create new nodes, when internal state is frozen

Tags: php, phpmd

I am tring to run [phpmd](http://phpmd.org) like this:

```
wget -c http://static.phpmd.org/php/latest/phpmd.phar
php phpmd.phar ./src text cleancode codesize
```

I get the following error message and I don't know what to do.

```
Cannot create new nodes, when internal state is frozen.
```

Comment: I suppose this is PHP 7 related? I'm getting this error too.

Comment: Yes it is. I figured out phpdepend threw this exception.

Comment: Getting the same error with PHP 5.5.9, so it is obviously not PHP7 related.

Comment: @Tihanyi Péter any updates on that?